# Having trouble converting SQL statement into Joomla formatting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla, sql-order-by

Here is the `SQL` statement that is working for me:

```
SELECT inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id, inl_cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id, inl_cbsubs_payment_items.stop_date, inl_cbsubs_payment_items.id FROM inl_cbsubs_subscriptions INNER JOIN inl_cbsubs_payment_items ON inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.id=inl_cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id WHERE inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id=596 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Here is my attempt of formatting this same query for Joomla:

```
$db2 = JFactory::getDbo();
$stopDateQuery = $db2->getQuery(true);

$stopDateQuery->select($db2->quoteName(array('#__cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id', '#__cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id', '#__cbsubs_payment_items.stop_date')));
$stopDateQuery->from($db2->quoteName('#__cbsubs_subscriptions'));
$stopDateQuery->innerJoin($db->quoteName('#__cbsubs_payment_items') . ' ON #__cbsubs_subscriptions.id = #__cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id');
$stopDateQuery->where($db2->quoteName('#__cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id')." = ".$db2->quote($myId));
$stopDateQuery->ORDER BY($db2->quoteName('#__cbsubs_payment_items.id'));
$stopDateQuery->DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I have tested the Joomla formatting and can get it to work if I remove the last two lines:

```
$stopDateQuery->ORDER BY($db2->quoteName('#__cbsubs_payment_items.id'));
$stopDateQuery->DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This tells me that the formatting problem is in that location.  It is a requirement that I add these additional filters to the query, so where did I go wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following (for Joomla 3.x+)

```
$stopDateQuery->order($db2->quoteName('#__cbsubs_payment_items.id') . 'DESC');
$stopDateQuery->setLimit(1);
```

If you're using Joomla 2.5, then use this to set the limit

```
$db2->setQuery($stopDateQuery,0,1);
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks.  It was Joomla 2.5 btw.

Comment: @Presto - Glad it works now :) Don't forget to accept the answer when possible

Answer (score 0):

As long as sql injection is not possible you can simply do this:

```
$stopDateQuery = "SELECT inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id, inl_cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id, inl_cbsubs_payment_items.stop_date, inl_cbsubs_payment_items.id FROM inl_cbsubs_subscriptions INNER JOIN inl_cbsubs_payment_items ON inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.id=inl_cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id WHERE inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id=596 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

It gets run a little faster too.

If sql injection is possible then you can use

```
$db2->quoteName($id)
```